# WPF UI in WinForms

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Is there some way that I can customize WinForm just like I can do it in WPF. Some code that will allow me that trought some sort of grid I customize it?
Buttons, tree view functions and similar things that will make customization easier unlike in WinForms where everything is so dull.
WPF doesn't support speech lib so that's why I'm asking this, otherwise I'll go for WPF.

Comment: If you're asking if you can use Winforms in the same way that you can use WPF, then the answer is no... it's WinForms. If you want what WPF has to offer, then use WPF.

Comment: The Windows Forms designer and the WPF designer are radically different, so probably not. The customization you speak of in WPF is virtually non existent in Windows Forms.

Comment: Please be aware that "everything is so dull" in WinForms primarily means that everything uses the preferred color scheme the user has configured on the target machine, and that controls tend to look the same across applications, thus lowering the entrance barrier. That may or may not be important for your project. That said, while there are less built-in means of visual customization, you are usually free to owner-draw WinForms controls.

Answer (score 5):

On this website, it is generally a good idea to actually ask for what you want, instead of what you have asked for. It *seems* to me as if what you *really* want is to use some sort of text to speech functionality with WPF... so why didn't you just ask 'can I use text to speech with WPF?' or something similar?

To answer *that* question, yes, you can do that with WPF. Please take a look at the following links:

[WPF Text To Speech UI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc998523.aspx)
[How to use the Speech Synthesizer in WPF](http://wpftutorial.net/SpeechSynthesizer.html)
[Using Speech Synthesis in a WPF Application](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2006/05/19/using-speech-synthesis-in-a-wpf-application.aspx)
[Speech Basics-WPF C# Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh855387.aspx)

Plenty more are available online.